# Handling with Bitmaps in RecyclerView

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerView` that has bitmaps. In addition, I use `LruCache`. When and where should I recycle the bitmaps in order to not get `OutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're observing? Why not cap the size of the cache, and let bitmaps get garbage collected as they would normally?

Comment: @DougStevenson, I have LruCache but still my app crash :(
I think because there is a reference to those bitmaps

Comment: OOM can be for many reasons other than bitmaps.  Consider profiling your app to see what are the worst offenders for allocations.  Also, please be sure your cache is capped in size so it doesn't get too big.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great set of official resources called [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), which should help you with your question. However, dealing with images properly is non-trivial, so if you're looking for a ready-made and stable solution - take a look at [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: Thanks I will take a look, but I saw Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently.... and still my app crash because of OutOfMemoryError because I can't find the best place to recycle the bitmaps

Comment: Netanel, I also had OutOfMemoryError, scale down your bitmaps using BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize property. Also take a look at [awesome lectures from Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY9aaXHx8yA)

Answer (score 0):

in your adapter override onViewRecycled() method and recycle the bitmaps.
Hope this helps !!!

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder)
    // do the bitmap recycling here
}
```